# Abrir link para o facebook no Safari do iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, link, safari

Cenário:

- Possuo um app, que tem um link para uma determinada página no facebook.
- Quando o usuário clica no link, ele deve ser dirigido a página e carrega-la com o Safari.
- Porém caso o usuário possua o App Facebook instalado no iPhone, o iOS direciona o link para o App e o App do Facebook não mostra a página.

  Alguém saberia como faço para determinar que um link deve obrigatoriamente ser aberto no Safari, e não pelo App do Facebook?

  Código usado: Objective-C.

Comment: Você está usando um `UIWebView`?

Comment: Não. Somente um link na action:

´ - (IBAction)linkFacebook:(id)sender {
    
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"https://www.facebook.com/********"]];
}´

Comment: Acho que encontrei uma solução, vou fazer alguns testes e conforme for vou informar aqui.

Comment: Bom a solução que tentei foi remover o "http://www." da urk ficando somente facebook.com/*****. Mas não funcionou.

Comment: Dá uma olhada [nessa](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22484852/1216394) questão lá do SO, acho que pode ajudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme o @PauloRodrigues me sugeriu no link>

Basta adicionar "`?ref=0`" no final da URL.

Sendo:

```
 www.facebook.com.br/PAGINA
```

Ficando

```
www.facebook.com.br/PAGINA?ref=0
```

Isso força o link ser aberto no Safari do iOS.

Comment: Engraçado que tanto no comentário lá em cima quanto aqui você me chamou de Paulo Roberto :)

Comment: Verdade,.. Desculpa... Kkkk esse Paulo Roberto é um amigo... Ai foi no automatico... Corrigindo!

Comment: Outro modo que você também pode usar para isso é colocando o "http://"

Comment: Gian, mesmo com "http://", e sem o "http://" não abre nem safari e nem o app facebook... simplesmente não acontece nada :D

Comment: Estranho, aqui para eu abrir no safari eu uso o http:// e solucionou meu problema...

Comment: Mas vc tem o app do facebook instalado no iPhone? Pois testei no 4S e no 6 e sempre abriu o app.

Answer (score 1):

Experimenta usar este método.
Apenas colocas o deepLink caso querias que a aplicação abra a aplicação do facebook, senão abre o Safari com o url dado.

Exemplo de um deep link (appURL): fb://page/id_pagina

Exemplo de um URL: https://www.facebook.com/something

```
+ (void)openSocialNetworkURLWith:(NSString *)appURL URL:(NSString *)url {

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:appURL]]) {

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:appURL]];

    } else {

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    }
}
```